# How to determine what web-server software is serving web pages, alternative to nc?

Tags: linux, webserver

How might I determine what web server software (and version) is serving web pages?

I'm using Linux, and I need an alternative to `nc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [nmap](http://nmap.org/), with attention to the `-sV` option.